# Android Application array to a textview on a new page

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I'm pretty new to Android programming, and at the moment I'm programming an application.

In my application you get a listview that is filled by an array. It is filled with names. When I click on the name, it opens a new screen. On that screen I have a textview. I want that textview to be filled by the clicked name of the listview(array).

I have tried to find it on the internet, tutorials for this, but couldn't find any. If anyone is able to help me out i'd appriciete it very much :)

Comment: are u successfully starting the new application? this is really simple using a `OnItemClickedListener` (to detect the click) and using an `Intent` to use with the `startActivity` function

Comment: OnItemClickedListener you get position and get value from that position of array and you get string value of array element and push to new activity.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you get to the new screen ( which I assume is an Activity ) via an Intent.

Once you have created the Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent (... );
```

you can add additional information to that intent.

```
intent.putExtra("param_name", value);
```

In the new Activity you can retrieve the intent with:

```
Intent callerIntent = getIntent();
if (callerIntent.hasExtra("param_name")) {
     int value = callerIntent.getIntExtra("param_name", default_value);
}
```

There a various types that the intent can hold as extra. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: then just put the "sipIntent.putExtra(...)" just before startActivity.

Comment: int value = callerIntent.getIntExtra("param_name"); doesn't work. it says getIntentExtra is wrong. =(

Comment: my bad. getIntExtra has a second parameter with the default parameter. i edited the answer

Comment: But what is the default value, and how to I get the info I took into a TextView? I can't just say EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNaamAgent); name.setText(callerIntent); or something like that. or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: then instead of using the selected index ( int value ) as int extra use the retrieved text as string (getStringExtra).

Comment: I tried this:
         String value = roepIntent.getStringExtra("clickedNaam");
         
         EditText naam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNaamAgent);
         naam.setText(value);

I get no error messages. but it ain't working, thanks btw for trying helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
intent.putExtra("clickedName", name[position]);
```

and in the next activity.

```
String clickedName = getIntent().getStringExtra("clickedName");
```

you use extras to pass simple information between activities.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.Write this function outside onCreate() metho5

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, your_target_activity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("name", your_array[position]);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivityForResult(i);
        finish();
    }
```